# Curly Parentheses After Return Type in Function Definition

Tags: scala, scala-cats

When read the [cats library's Functor source](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/cats/Functor.scala), I could not understand what the curly block after the return type of the function **toFunctorOps** does; My guess is that this block will be executed as part of constructor? If so, then why type **TypeClassType** is defined twice with the same code **type TypeClassType = Functor[F]**?

```
  trait Ops[F[_], A] extends Serializable {
    type TypeClassType <: Functor[F]
    def self: F[A]
    val typeClassInstance: TypeClassType
    def map[B](f: A => B): F[B] = typeClassInstance.map[A, B](self)(f)
    ...
  }

  trait ToFunctorOps extends Serializable {
    implicit def toFunctorOps[F[_], A](target: F[A])(implicit tc: Functor[F]): Ops[F, A] {
      type TypeClassType = Functor[F]
    } =
      new Ops[F, A] {
        type TypeClassType = Functor[F]
        val self: F[A] = target
        val typeClassInstance: TypeClassType = tc
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I could not understand what the curly block after the return type ... does

The refinement `{ type TypeClassType = Functor[F] }` puts a further constraint on type member `TypeClassType` of trait `Ops`. In other words it gives more information to the compiler about the specific return type of method `toFunctorOps`

```
Ops[F, A] { type TypeClassType = Functor[F] }
```

Note the refinement block is considered **part** of the return type and has nothing to do with the constructor.

Let us simplify the types to illustrate the concept better, so consider

```
trait Foo {
  type A
  def bar: A
}

val foo: Foo = new Foo { 
  type A = Int 
  def bar: A = ???
}
val x: foo.A = 42 // type mismatch error
```

Note how static type of variable `foo` does not include specific information that type member `A` has been instantiated to `Int`. Now let's give the compiler this information by using type refinement

```
val foo: Foo { type A = Int } = new Foo { 
  type A = Int
  def bar: A = ??? 
}
val x: foo.A = 42 // ok
```

Now compiler knows that type member `A` is precisely an `Int`.

Designers of type classes make judicious decisions regarding when to use type members as opposed to type parameters, and sometimes there is even a mix of the two as in your case. For example trait `Foo` could have been parameterised like so

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def bar: A
}
val foo: Foo[Int] = new Foo[Int] { 
  def bar: Int = ??? 
}
```

and compiler would again have precise information that type parameter `A` has been instantiated to `Int`.

> why type TypeClassType is defined twice

The refined type `Foo { type A = Int }` is a narrower subtype of `Foo`, similar to how `Cat` is a narrower subtype of `Animal`

```
implicitly[(Foo { type A = Int }) <:< Foo]
implicitly[Cat <:< Animal]
```

so even though the right-hand side expression instantiates `A` as `Int`, the left-hand side explicitly told the compiler that the static type of `foo` is just the wider supertype `Foo`

```
val foo: Foo = new Foo { 
  type A = Int 
  def bar: A = ???
}
```

similarly to how compiler knows that static type of `zar` below is only the wider supertype `Animal` despite the expression on the RHS specifying a `Cat`

```
val zar: Animal = new Cat
```

Hence the need for "double" type specification

```
val foo: Foo { type A = Int } = new Foo { 
  type A = Int 
  ...
}
```

similar to

```
val zar: Cat = new Cat
```

We could try to rely on inference to deduce the most specific type, however when we are explicitly annotating types then we have to provide the full information which includes the type member constraints via refinements.