# How to get case class field names and values as (String, String) with Shapeless or Macro

Tags: scala, macros, shapeless

I have been struggling for a couple days already to try to create a macro or use shapeless to create a method/function to extract field names and values as a Tuple[String, String].

Lets imagine the following case class:

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

I want to have something like this (doesn't really need to be a method in case class).

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
    def fields: List[(String, String)] = ???
}

// or

def fields[T](caseClass: T): List[(String, String)] = ???
```

I've seen quite few similar solutions here but I can't make it work with my use case of (String, String)

I would also appreciate some literature to learn and expand my knowledge regarding macros, I have both Programming in Scala(Third Edition by Martin) and Programming Scala (O'REILLY - Dean Wampler & Alex Payne) and only O'REILLY has a very small chapter regarding macros and to be honest its very lacking.

PD: I'm using Scala 2.12.12 so I don't have those fancy new methods for case class **productElementNames** and such :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on `LabelledGeneric` and `Keys` type classes

```
import shapeless.LabelledGeneric
import shapeless.HList
import shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable
import shapeless.ops.record.Keys

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

def fields[P <: Product, L <: HList, R <: HList](a: P)(
  implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L],
  keys: Keys.Aux[L, R],
  ts: ToTraversable.Aux[R, List, Symbol]
): List[(String, String)] = {
  val fieldNames = keys().toList.map(_.name)
  val values = a.productIterator.toList.map(_.toString)
  fieldNames zip values
}

fields(Person("Jean-Luc, Picard", 70))
// : List[(String, String)] = List((name,Jean-Luc, Picard), (age,70))
```

[scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mwHodWZaSZWWB3AWS8346g)

> IDEA ... shows an error ... No implicit arguments

IntelliJ in-editor error highlighting is [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62286141/5205022) not 100% accurate when it comes to type-level code and macros. Best is to consider it as just guidance, and put trust in the Scala compiler proper, so if compiler is happy but IJ is not, then go with the compiler. Another options is to try Scala [Metals](https://scalameta.org/metals/) which should have one-to-one mapping between compiler diagnostics and in-editor error highlighting.

> why you used LabelledGeneric.Aux, Keys.Aux, ToTraversable.Aux

This is using a design pattern called type classes. My suggestion would be to work through [The Type Astronaut's Guide to Shapeless](https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide) in particular section on [Chaining dependent functions](https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide/blob/110d34792457e1edccb9f9361a3074a1a6640df9/src/pages/type-level-programming/dependent-functions.md#chaining-dependent-functions-sectype-level-programmingchaining)

> Dependently typed functions provide a means of calculating one type
> from another. We can chain dependently typed functions to perform
> calculations involving multiple steps.

Consider the following dependency between types

```
                input type
                         |
gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L],
                            |
                            output type
 
      input type
               |
keys: Keys.Aux[L, R]
                  |
                  output type
```

Note how for example the output type `L` of `LabelledGeneric` becomes the input type of `Keys`. In this way you are showing the compiler the relationship between the types and in return the compiler is able to give your an `HList` representing the field names from `Product` representing the particular case class, and all this before the program even runs.

`ToTraversable` is needed so you can get back a regular Scala `List` from an `HList` which enables the following bit

```
.toList.map(_.name)
```

Hopefully this gives you at least a little bit of direction. Some keywords to search for are: type classes, dependent types, implicit resolution, type alias [Aux pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60588240/5205022), type members vs type parameters, [type refinement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354828/5205022), etc. Typelevel community has a new Discord [channel](https://typelevel.org/blog/2021/05/05/discord-migration.html) where you can get further direction.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. Thank you! Questions:
1) IDEA Idea is not able to see implicit Attributes[A] so despite compilation is ok, it shows an error like this: No implicit arguments of type: Attributes[CaseClass] anything we might need to add? or just ignore?

3)I think I get the general idea of what your code, but I'd love to understand it more, would be possible for you to give an explanation of what it actually does and why you used LabelledGeneric.Aux, Keys.Aux, ToTraversable.Aux, trait Attributes[T] and so on? I'd love to be able to craft solutions like yours! Thank you really!

Comment: @envy Please see edited answer. I have tried to simplify the solution and give some further pointers.

Comment: Thank you! @mario-galic really appreciate your detailed answer now I understand it a little more. I'll make sure to read that book and search for the topics you mentioned! Have a great weekend!

Comment: I found this is also very helpful:  https://svejcar.dev/posts/2019/10/22/extracting-case-class-field-names-with-shapeless/ where it extracts the field names as generic

Comment: I also have a Q:  what is the pros and cons of this shapeless approach vs scala-reflect approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16079804/4582240 , @MarioGalic; i do find the reflect approach requires the case class to be top level.

Comment: @soMuchToLearnAndShare In general the difference is reflection happens at run-time (that is only at the point when your program is executing) whilst shapeless happens at compile time (that is at the point when compiler is executing), so shapeless is much safer as you get full aid of compile-time compiler verification of correctness so there are less things that can explode at run-time.